# Need secure header code in java

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, soap-client

I need to access the secure webservice. I need to pass the secure header in the soap request.Please help me to provide the custom secure header code in java.

Requirement:

```
   <soapenv:Header>

 <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">

  <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
    <wsse:Username>XYZ</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">security</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
```

i Appreciate if any one help me on this.`

Answer (score 3):

Seems pretty clear that you want to add a UsernameToken security header. There are at least a couple of different ways of doing this. If you have a WSDL service definition which includes the WS-SecurityPolicy component you can just set the appropriate properties to define the username and password values, as shown in [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws13/index.html) article

If you want to set this up directly (without using a policy), you can do so in your client code. Here's a sample of how this would work:`

```
    // create the client stub
    MyService service = new MyService();
    MyServicePort stub = service.getMyServicePort();

    // configure UsernameToken security handling
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "XYZ");
    props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordHandler.class.getName());
    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(props);
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(stub);
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

...

```
/**
 * Callback for password used by WS-Security UsernameToken.
 */
public static class PasswordHandler implements CallbackHandler
{
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) {
        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
            pc.setPassword("security");
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

thanks you for your support. I used the following code for secure header , it is working fine for me.

```
SOAPHeaderElement wsseSecurity = new SOAPHeaderElement(new PrefixedQName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext","Security", "wsse"));
            wsseSecurity.setMustUnderstand(false);
            wsseSecurity.setActor(null);
            SOAPElement sub = wsseSecurity.addChildElement("UsernameToken");
            sub.setAttribute("xmlns:wsu", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility");
            SOAPElement userElement = sub.addChildElement("Username");
            userElement.addTextNode("XYZ");         
            SOAPElement pwdElement = sub.addChildElement("Password");
            pwdElement.setAttribute("Type", "wsse:PasswordText");
            pwdElement.addTextNode("security");
            _stub.setHeader(wsseSecurity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear! 
Take a look at the [article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
BTW 
If you mean having security on transport level protocols like HTTPS , you may see [Apache CXF SSl support](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html).
If you mean WS-Security above and beyond transport level protocols, such as XML-Encryption or X509 you may see [Apache CXF WS-Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html)